# Writing a twice differentiable function as a linear combionation of exponentials

Tags: analysis, derivatives, exponential-function

Let $I$ a non-trivial interval and $f \in D^{2}(I)$ such that $f''(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in I$. Show that, if there exists some $a \in I$ such that $f(a) = f'(a) = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in I$.

My attempt:

A reasonable guess I've been pondering is that $f$ could be written as

$$f(x) = be^{x}+ce^{-x},\ \ b, c \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Because $f'(x) = be^{x}-ce^{-x}$ and so

$$ f''(x) = be^{x}+ce^{-x} = f(x).$$

And also, that would imply that

$$
be^{a}+ce^{-a} = 0\\
be^{a}-ce^{-a} = 0
$$

which gives $b=c=0$ and so $f$ is the zero map. The question is how are $b$ and $c$ suppossed to look like? Because if I treat $b$ and $c$ as unkowns in a $2x2$ system I get

$$b = \left(\frac{f(x)+f'(x)}{2}\right)e^{-x}\\
  c= \left(\frac{f(x)-f'(x)}{2}\right)e^{x}
$$
which doesn´t make any sense to me. Any hint someone could give me? Is my original guess a reasonable one?

Comment: I didn't get your question. $b=c=0$. You said it.

Comment: Yes, but first I need to show that $f$ can be written in such a way. How can I prove that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form of solutions of linear ODEs with constant coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136276/form-of-solutions-of-linear-odes-with-constant-coefficients) $\quad$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Comment: I’ll take a look, but haven’t learnt about differential equations yet so I don’t know if it will be 100% helpful.

Comment: Your guess was very astute. Observe that the solutions to this differential equation form a vector space -- if you add two solutions or multiply a solution by a constant, you get another solution. In this case, it turns out that the solution space is $2$-dimensional. Therefore, since $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ are both linearly independent elements of this space, all solutions are of the form you stated, and assuming this dimensionality result (as you noted, an extra detail is needed to complete the proof), your argument is entirely correct.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that I still haven´t taken differential equations. Showing that $\{e^{x}, e^{-x}\}$ is a linearly independent set is easy, since the exponential is injective and strictly positive. However, showing that $span (e^{x}, e^{-x})$ equals the set of solutions of $g'' = g$ is not as clear based on what I know right now.

Comment: @MrGran I know that. I was only explaining the context of your question further.